# 事に感ず and Shigin vocabulary

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, poetry

I recently heard of the poem named Koto ni Kanzu, and I came across [this page](http://shigin.com/hiroaki/kansi_syuu/kansi_syuu-13/kotonikanzu.htm) that provides the poem's text, along with a pretty convincing interpretation.
The poems reads as follows (I only added the furigana for the words my question focuses on):

> 花開けば蝶枝に満つ
>
> 花謝すれば蝶[還]{また}稀なり
>
> 惟旧巣の燕[有]{あ}あり
>
> 主人貧しきも[亦]{また}帰る

I have the following questions regarding the vocabulary used in this poem:

- Why is `還` read `また`? I found the kanji in Jisho, which says that it can be used instead of `帰` in `帰{か}える`, but I could not find it being used as `また`. Is this some kind of play on words based on this kanji's meaning of `returning`?
- Why are `還` and `亦` both used for `また`? Is there a negative connotation in the former, and a positive in the latter? What about `又`?
- What is the meaning of `有あり`?

Comment: 有あり is probably a typo. According to [this page](http://www.kangin.or.jp/learning/text/chinese/k_A3_091.html) it is [有]{あ}りて.

Comment: 有りて would be an archaism for 有って? Or a poetic version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Background

The first thing to be aware of is that this poem was composed in Chinese by the poet 于 濆 (Yú Fén) in roughly 874.  (Brief Chinese Wikipedia article about the poet [here](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8E%E6%BF%86).)  As such, the Japanese version must be viewed as a translation.  And if you've ever done much translation yourself, particularly of poetry, you've probably come to understand that certain liberties are often taken in order to produce a target text that 1) is meaningful, and 2) works at least somewhat as poetry.

Here's the original as best I can tell, with the modern Mandarin readings and a rough English translation.

> 花開蝶滿枝，花謝蝶還稀。
>     *Huā kāi dié mǎn zhī, huā xiè dié hái xī.*
>     Flowers open and butterflies fill the branches, flowers say goodbye and butterflies go back to being scarce.
>   惟有舊巢燕，主人貧亦歸。
>     *Wéi yǒu jiù cháo yàn, zhǔrén pín yì guī.*
>     However, there are old-nest swallows, the house owner is poor and yet they come back.

### Specifics

With that in mind, let's address your questions.

> - Why is `還` read `また`? I found the kanji in Jisho, which says that it can be used instead of `帰` in `帰{か}える`, but I could not find it being used as `また`. Is this some kind of play on words based on this kanji's meaning of `returning`?

[As Chinese, 還 has various senses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%82%84#Chinese), of which the "returning, going back" one seems most relevant here.  In the context of the poem, the text is describing how the butterflies *go back to* being rare, which can be expressed in Japanese using the word また.

> - Why are `還` and `亦` both used for `また`? Is there a negative connotation in the former, and a positive in the latter? What about `又`?

Again, the Japanese for this poem is a translation.  The use of the Japanese word また fits the context, the grammar, the meaning, and (to a lesser extent) the meter.

The kanji are, strictly speaking, *hanzi* (漢字 as read in Mandarin).

- In the first case with 還, the text is describing the butterfly situation *returning* to a previous state of few butterflies.
- In the second case with 亦, and [using the *although* sense for the Chinese term](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A6#Chinese), the text is describing that the swallows mentioned in the previous line return home *even though* the master of the house is poor.  In the Japanese, this *although, even though* sense is conveyed using the particle も, and the また was probably added to reinforce the 歸【かえる】 meaning and to fill out the otherwise-missing syllables needed to approach the expected meter.

> - What is the meaning of `有あり`?

As noted in the comment by Sweeper, that's a typo.  It should be 有【あ】りて, which you correctly guessed is an archaic form of modern あって.

#### Digression: alternative approaches to translingual poetry

As 漢文訓読【かんぶんくんどく】 (literally "Chinese text, [Japanese] meaning-reading"), one of the common renderings appears to be:

> 花【はな】開【ひら】けば 蝶【ちょう】枝【えだ】に滿【み】つ
>   花【はな】謝【しゃ】すれば 蝶【ちょう】還【また】稀【まれ】なり
>   惟【ただ】 舊巣【きゅうそう】の 燕【つばめ】有【あ】りて
>   主人【しゅじん】 貧【まず】しきも 亦【また】歸【かえ】る

Going slightly further and reworking a bit to better fit the Japanese poetic meter preference for lines of 5 and 7 morae, we might get:

> 花【はな】が開【ひら】けば
>   蝶【ちょう】枝【えだ】に満【み】ち
>   花【はな】が謝【しゃ】すれば
>   蝶【ちょう】また稀【まれ】に
>   惟【ただ】舊巣【きゅうそう】の
>   燕【つばめ】が有【あ】りて
>   主【ぬし】貧【まず】しきも
>   また歸【かえ】る

And treating this more as a translation than just 漢文訓読, we might even change some wording around while maintaining the meaning, particulary reworking the end.

> 花【はな】が開【ひら】けば
>   蝶【ちょう】枝【えだ】に満【み】ち
>   花【はな】が謝【しゃ】すれば
>   蝶【ちょう】また稀【まれ】に
>   それはともあれ
>   古巣【ふるす】の燕【つばめ】
>   家【いえ】主【ぬし】が
>   貧【まず】しく然【さ】るに
>   また帰【かえ】る

---

Please comment if the above does not fully address your questions.